# Can I make an external map on Google Maps that only shows hospital or any tag?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Can I make an external map on Google Maps that only shows hospitals?

Based on the location of the user or in search of Postal Code, I would like the map to suggest only pharmacies, or hospitals, etc., ignoring other points or departments ...

thank you!

Comment: Please read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i believe its possible but will require some code effort. please have a look at google maps api specifically places api for more information.

Comment: Thanks, @MotiKorets, you helped me a lot. The Google Places API is exactly what i need! And thanks Cmac and Alon.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/).
Here is an example of searching restaurants nearby and showing markers on the map.

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    type: ['restaurant']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```